# Trying to Scrape a Span

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I 've been trying to scrape two values from a website using beautiful soup in Python, and it's been giving me trouble. Here is the URL of the page I'm scraping:
https://www.stjosephpartners.com/Home/Index

Here are the values I'm trying to scrape:
[HTML of Website to be Scraped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USfVh.png)

I tried:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.stjosephpartners.com/Home/Index').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

gold_spot_shell = soup.find('div', class_ = 'col-lg-10').children

print(gold_spot_shell)
```

the output I got was: `<list_iterator object at 0x039FD0A0>`

When I tried using: `gold_spot_shell = soup.find('div', class_ = 'col-lg-10').children`

The output was: `['\n']`

when I tried using: `gold_spot_shell = soup.find('div', class_ = 'col-lg-10').span`

The output was: `none`

The HTML definitely has at least one span child. I'm not sure how to scrape the values I'm after. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Beautifulsoup` + `Request` is not a good method to **scrape** dynamic website like this. That span is generated by javascript so when you get the html using request, it just does not exist.

You can try to use selenium instead.

You can check if the website is using javascript to render element or not by disabling javascript on the page and find that element again, or just "view page source"